# any downsides in casting string-integer to integer in Javascript with ( 1*x )?

Tags: javascript, casting, integer

if you compare different explicit methods of type-casting a variable to integer:

`var y = parseInt(x,10) + 'text';` // too long, needs wrapping, needs anti-octal hack

`var y = x.toFixed(0)  + 'text';` // still long, and even uglier, and maybe buggy

`var y = Math.floor(x)  + 'text';` // long and uses Math object

`var y = Number(x)  + 'text';` // long

`var y =  +x + 'text';` // very short, but too hacky

`var y = 1 * x + 'text';` // simple and short

You will see, why the last one is my favourite. Yet, i wonder, if there are any hidden issues with this method ?

Comment: `Number(x)` seems pretty explicit and acceptably terse (compare that to `document.getElementById`!) to me.

Comment: I prefer the unary plus because that's its specified purpose: http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last one does work:

```
1 * 0.5; // 0.5
```

if you want the best readiblilty use parseInt. And the radix is not a hack!

Edit:

My favorite:

```
var y = x|0 + 'text';
```

---

Edit: Please do note that this "trick" only works with 32-bit signed integers. Because that's JavaScript's implementation of it's bit logic. So the largest positive number you can use this for is 2147483647.

There is one unsigned bit operation, unsigned right shift. `0 >>> 1`

Comment: lol, true, its not converting to integer, lol. (yet, this does not concern me much, i just want to make sure its not a string) About readability - `parseInt` imho, decreases it, not improves.

Comment: It will become NaN after next calculation, but yes, NaN too. Sometimes you just want numbers to stay numbers.

Comment: You did ) Just want to hear other answers, hoping that there is something else, we both haven't thought about. And, regarding your method, - maybe `0|x` is better than `x|0`, readability wise ?

Comment: **Update:** `1326394630086|0` gives `-750264378`, so i would really discourage anyone from using it.

Comment: That's an overflow. Because | only works with 32-bit signed integers which would make the largest positive number possible 2147483647

Answer (score 1):

I believe that code should first be correct, then as readable as possible to as many other people as you can and lastly no longer than required.  In that vein, here are my preferences:

For conversion from string to integer, I prefer:

```
parseInt(x, 10)
```

because I think the code says exactly what you're trying to do.  If you don't like the extra parameter, you can define your own global utility function:

```
toInt(x) {return(parseInt(x, 10));}
```

so you can just use:

```
toInt(x)
```

When I just want to turn a string into a number, I prefer:

```
Number(x)
```

because again I think it's the most explicit and the most readable.

In the other examples you have, `x.toFixed(0)` does not work if x is a string and `Number(x)`, `+x` and `1*x` do not convert to an integer.